# How to use ORDER by names after ordered by dates?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM makale ORDER BY date ASC";
```

how can I add another ORDER after date ...?

I want rows ordered by dates and if same dates will be ordered by name ?

How can I do that?

Comment: ORDER BY date ASC", <someothercolumn> and do read the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html where example are given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add after first field:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM makale ORDER BY date ASC, name DESC";
```

You can read, about this, [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-order-by/)

Answer (score 1):

To add multiple order conditions to your SQL query you can just list them separated by commas, i.e.

`SELECT * FROM makale ORDER BY date ASC, name`

This will order the results by date first then if there are the same dates it will order them according to their names. 
NOTE:- Order preference will be set by the order of columns occurring in your query. 
Check this out for more info https://www.dofactory.com/sql/order-by